# Firestore Timestamp not being recognized as such in the console

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a script which loads some data into Firestore from a excel sheet. For each entry that is loaded in, I want to add two fields, `dateAdded` and `dateModified`.

```js
const service:Service = {
   name: data.PROFISSIONAL,
   description: data.DESCRICAO,
   category: data.CLASSIFICACAO,
   cellphones,
   phones,
   reviews: reviews,
   numReviews: reviews.length,
   excluded: data.EXCLUIDO === 'SIM',
   instagram: data.INSTAGRAM,
   location: data.LOCAL,
   dateAdded: Timestamp.now(),
   dateModified: Timestamp.now(),
   tags: getTags(data.CLASSIFICACAO)
};
```

I have a intermediate step which saves an array of these services to a json object. The data then gets uploaded to firestore:

```js
const jsonToFirestore = async () => {
  console.log(`Uploading table`)

  try {
    console.log('Initializing Firebase');
    initializeApp(serviceAccount);
    console.log('Firebase Initialized');

    await restore('./data/services.json');
    console.log('Upload Success');
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

When I look in the Firebase console though, the date fields have not been recognized as Timestamps.

[image: Firestore console dates not recognized]

Is there any way for them to be recognized? Like this for example:

[image: Firestore console dates recognized]

I appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this format of the [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) is working as expected:

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or
> calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
> nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

Try using the [`toDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method in order to convert a `Timestamp` to a JavaScript `Date` object.